# Design Self-Sizing UITableViewCell using .xib, cell doesn't adjust itself in interface builder

Tags: ios, xib

I'm trying to use .xib file to design a self-sizing UITableViewCell. However, the cell doesn't adjust it's height according to it's content subviews. I have to adjust cell manually. If the cell is too large, a subview will be stretched to fill the cell. And if the cell is too small, there will be some constraint error alert by interface builder.

The UI is correct when running, but is broken when designing.

[image]

[image]

When using a .storyboard file to design a self-sizing cell, it works great. The cell can grow or shrink automatically.

[image]

Is this a limitation of the .xib file? Or did I miss something?

Answer (score 0):

If you set constraints properly, the UILabel will be set its height and width as per the set constrains and its content.

All you need to do is...

For the first label you need to set Leading, top and trailing constraint
For the second label you need to set Leading, top constraint with the bottom of first constraint, and finally trailing and bottom constraint to the superview.

Do not forgot to set the number of line equal to zero & Line break mode to Word Wrap in the Attribute Inspector.

[image]

Also need to set the following

[image]

Answer (score 0):

We *could* consider it a "limitation" ... but it's more a matter of "by design."

When laying out UI elements in Storyboard (including a Prototype Cell), Interface Builder (**IB**) does a lot of additional work. For an obvious example, you can change the Orientation and your prototype cell will automatically expand its width.

When developing a XIB, though, IB doesn't change your root view's size on its own. Think of it as IB saying "you're designing a XIB, you know what you're doing and you know exactly what you want."

While it's generally a good idea to follow IB's advice and get rid of any "constraint error alerts" it's not required.

There *are* legitimate instances when designing a cell (or other view) in a XIB where you ***cannot*** eliminate all constraint warnings. For example, if I put a `UIScrollView` in my cell XIB, but the scroll view will not have any content until run-time, IB will tell me it has "Ambiguous scrollable content size." In this case, I **know** my constraints are correct, and I **know** the content size won't be defined until I add and constrain subviews at run-time... so I can ignore the warning.

If you find it a hassle to manually resize the cell, but not see constraint warnings, you can (for this example) if your bottom-most constraint is Zero, give it a Priority of 999, or set it to `>= 0` ... or, change the Ambiguity option to either:

[image]

or:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First set top, left, right constraints of first label and bottom, top, right, left constraints of second label with cell.

```
 Set Lines of labels to 0 then it will work as you are expecting.
```